# Why do I get a build error in a WPF UserControl and its owner Window only at design time?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism, prism-6

I have a `MainMenu` user control that I use in my `MainWindow` view, which has a `MainWindowViewModel`. `MainMenu` markup begins like:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ApptEase.Client.Shell.Controls.MainMenu"
             ....
             d:DesignHeight="25">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <shell:MainWindowViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Menu Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
```

In design mode I get 2 errors in my Error List, both are:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Application' to type
>   'ApptEase.Client.App'

The first occurs in the `<shell:MainWindowViewModel />` line in the user control markup above. The second occurs in the `<shell:MainMenu Grid.Row="0" />` line of the `MainWindow` markup excerpt below.

MainWindow Excerpt:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <shell:MainMenu Grid.Row="0" />
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" />
</Grid>
```

My `MainWindowViewModel` derives from `BaseViewModel`:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel : BindableBase
{
    protected BaseViewModel()
    {
        AppState = ((App)Application.Current).AppState;
    }
    ...
}
```

If I comment out the `((App)Application.Current).AppState` line, the errors disappear. Yet I see no output except "successful build" in the output window when I build, and the app starts up fine, i.e. the `BaseViewModel` ctor executes fine with no exception.

If I have no option but to accept the error messages are harmless, is there any way to suppress them? I don't see compiler directives working in XAML markup.

Comment: Could you provide full example (probably as an archive)? I'm not familiar with prism, but this looks like problem with App.xaml / App.xaml.cs

Comment: @cdmnk I created a new project, with only two simple additions, based on the Prism Unity project template, but the basic app is only using Unity to show the main window. You can see the error if you do a build. Here is a link to my Google drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzxhSNxuhN5OUEV1RG1PWGtualk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @cdmnk I think it may be something along the lines that at design time, `Application.Current` is not of type `App`, but only at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is just a 'catch-all' or a proper solution, but I have solved my problem by changing my `BaseViewModel` ctor to look like:

```
protected BaseViewModel()
{
    if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
    {
        _app = (App)Application.Current;
    }
}
```

It seems that in design mode, `Application.Current` is not of type `App`.